# getting exception while trying to query xdocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I am trying to extract the data from Web response having XML format using the below code 
but I am getting null reference exception here at this line  **var status = html.Element("Status");**

```
if (oHttpWebResponse.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower() == "ok")
    {
        string contentType = oHttpWebResponse.ContentType;
        Stream content = oHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(XDocument.Load(content));
        var html = xDoc.Root.Element("html");
        var status = html.Element("Status"); // getting System.NullReferenceException here 
       var statusValue = status.Value;
        var lice = html.Element("LicenseKey").Value;

    }
```

I am not why i am getting this error and xml format looks like this ..

```
<html>
<Status>
200
</Status>
<LicenseKey>
FXOZ-HTTEKG-3QYB-MP2NPQ-AC7I3C-76SX-DVN4BA-C55RMK-RV2P-O5NSOQ
</LicenseKey>
<CustomerId>
U2N3XCAV
</CustomerId>
</html>
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error, If any one please help on this query that would be very grateful to me ..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Code looks Ok, although the way you create/load the xdoc is silly. So post the _exact_ xml, I suspect there is a namespace somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`xDoc.Root` is the whole text, since the root is the `html` tag. It has no child elements.
In order to fetch an element based on its name, you can run the following code:

```
var status = xDoc.Root.Elements("Status").FirstOrDefault();
// ensure not null is assigned to "stringValue"
var statusValue = status==null? String.Empty: status.Value;
```

After C# 6.0, you can use this assignment as well to ensure `null` is not assigned to `stringValue`:

```
statusValue = status?.Value ?? String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

`xDoc.Root` is the "html" tag in this xml document, so you are looking for an "html" child element under this "html" tag that is why it is null.